# strtotime() in SELECT query on Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Using get_calendar() function in Wordpress as a reference, I would like to show on the calendar the event dates (meta_value = 'event_date') of my custom post type (events).

This is how I get all event dates in a month. I couldn't make the strtotime() work. Am I doing it right?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$thisyear' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /.../wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/runtime.php(42) : eval()'d
>   code on line 18

```
<?php

    global $wpdb, $posts, $postmeta;

    // To simplify codes
    $thisyear = 2016;
    $thismonth = 06;
    $last_day = 30;
    $cpt = 'events';

    // Get days with events
    $dayswithevents = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *
        FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta 
        WHERE $wpdb->post.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
        AND $wpdb->post_type = '$cpt' 
        AND $wpdb->post_status = 'publish'
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_event_date'; 
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value >= 'strtotime("$thisyear-$thismonth-01 00:00:00")'
        AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value <= 'strtotime("$thisyear-$thismonth-{$last_day} 23:59:59")'", ARRAY_N);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using quote in the wrong way

```
  $dayswithevents = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *
    FROM '$wpdb->posts', '$wpdb->postmeta' 
    WHERE '$wpdb->post.ID' = '$wpdb->postmeta.post_id'
    AND  '$wpdb->post_type' = '$cpt' 
    AND  '$wpdb->post_status' = `publish`
    AND  '$wpdb->postmeta.meta_key' = `_eventpro_event_date`; 
    AND  '$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value' >= strtotime( '$thisyear-$thismonth-01 00:00:00') 
    AND   '$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value'  <= strtotime('$thisyear-$thismonth-{$last_day} 23:59:59')", ARRAY_N);
```

Comment: I see, thanks. No more error but I the output array is empty. I wonder what's wrong with the logic

Comment: `AND  '$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value' >= strtotime( '$thisyear-$thismonth-01 00:00:00') ` is not working. I ended up putting `$date1 = strtotime("$thisyear-$thismonth-01 00:00:00");` outside the query, then do `AND  meta_value >= $date1`

Comment: You have posted a original question about a  sintax error  my answer solve this error and you change the question about the logic..this is not fair  . the rule in SO  is on question only by time and the if you have others then post new question .. i suggestion you of posting a new question specifically  related to your problem with the logic of strtotime,..

Comment: no, it's not about the logic. This syntax seems not correct `AND '$wpdb->postmeta.meta_value' >= strtotime( '$thisyear-$thismonth-01 00:00:00')` . Please try and see.

Comment: have you a sintax error from  db ?

Comment: Your problem is related to the fact you are mixing date and number in php  $thisyear-$thismonth (eg 2016 - 03)  = 2013 .. .. so $thisyear-$thismonth-01 00:00:00 produce wrong result ..

Comment: but I got the correct one when I use `$date1 = strtotime("$thisyear-$thismonth-01 00:00:00");`

Comment: you have correct wrong .. becase so don't work .. if don't respect the correct sequence of quotes (doble quotes) you obtain a wrong sql command .. was  you original problem ..

Comment: agree, my usage of code is wrong. but still couldn't make your query work eventhough there's no error. Any, really appreciate your time. Thanks